# View information on historical deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, deadlock

I've been tasked with investigating an issue where an application's job has failed due to deadlocks. I'm aware of using traces to capture deadlocks, however as this is something that occurred 16 hours ago I wanted to know if it was possible to see what caused the deadlock?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with [sp_BlitzLock](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/introducing-sp_blitzlock-troubleshooting-sql-server-deadlocks/). It's a free open source stored procedure written by Erik Darling that examines the built-in System Health Extended Events session in SQL Server 2012 & newer.

You can download it from the [First Responder Kit Github repository](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/main).

To install it, just run sp_BlitzLock.sql to install the stored procedure, then run:

```
EXEC sp_BlitzLock
```

The first result set is a set of deadlock details, and the second is analysis that looks at which apps, users, and tables are most commonly involved in your deadlocks. It also gives you parameters to use for sp_BlitzCache to analyze their query plans, and sp_BlitzIndex to analyze over-indexing and under-indexing issues on the tables that may be contributing.

Comment: @Krishn needs to extract the info as soon as possible. The system_health trace targets are a ring buffer and rollover file with 4 files of 5MB each max. A deadlock that occurred 16 hours ago may or may not be available depending on the size of data captured since the deadlock occurred.

Comment: I cannot emphasize my joy that of all people, Brent Ozar has answered my question, Dan Guzman has commented and Erik Darling edited my question.

Comment: HAHAHA, awesome. I know that feeling too. Never gets old. And the whole thing was free.

Comment: How can i increase the size of this deadlock, or create a trigger which can input this entire information into some table for permanent storage and analysis at any point of time?

Comment: Or should I create a job which runs this script once every hour, and then do the necessary work?

Comment: Generally speaking, I’m not a fan of hoarding data for no reason: when you’re ready to analyze deadlocks, run the script. If you don’t have time to analyze them, don’t run the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled traceflag 1222 (DBCC TRACEON (1222, -1)) you can read deadlock information from the Errorlog

With the following query you can read all deadlock information from the Errorlog

```
declare @RawLogs table (id int IDENTITY (1, 1), logdate datetime, processinfo nvarchar(50), logtext nvarchar(max))

insert into @RawLogs
exec sp_readerrorlog

declare @results table (id int IDENTITY (1,1), logdate datetime, processinfo nvarchar(50), logtext nvarchar(max))
declare @ids table (id int, processinfo nvarchar(50))

insert into @ids
select id, processinfo
from @RawLogs
where logteXt = 'deadlock-list'
order by id

declare @Startid int, @endid int, @processinfo nvarchar(50)
select top 1 @Startid = id from @ids order by id
while(@@rowcount<>0)
begin
    select @processinfo = processinfo from @ids where id = @Startid
    select top 1 @endid = id from @ids where id > @Startid and processinfo = @processinfo order by id
    insert into @results (logdate, processinfo, logtext)
    select logdate, processinfo, logtext
    from @RawLogs
    where
       id >=@Startid and
       processinfo = @processinfo and
       id < @endid
    order by id
    delete @ids where id = @Startid
    select top 1 @Startid = id from @ids order by id
end

select logdate, processinfo, logtext
from @results
order by id
```